# How to make javax Transformer output HTML (no self-closing tags)?

Tags: java, html, xslt

I'm using a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` to convert an XML file into an HTML file. It can happen that a `div` will have no content, which causes the Transformer to output `<div/>`, which breaks rendering.

I've searched and [found](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst9718_XSLT-div-tag-output.aspx) that "*You can **change the xslt output to html** instead of xml to avoid the problem with self closing tags*", but that was for a different tool and I'm left wondering: **how do I do that** with a `javax` `Transformer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560762/xslt-wont-allow-me-to-use-self-closing-img-and-br-tags/1560815#1560815%5D) doesn't seem to work in my case; even if I specify `<xsl:output method="html"...>` it still produces `<div/>` instead of `<div></div>`.

I don't know if my IDE or compiler is broken (IBM Rational Application Developer), but I'm using a work-around of detecting blank nodes and inserting single spaces in them. Less clean, but effective...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you create the transformer as normal, and then use [Transformer.setOutputProperty](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to set the [METHOD](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#METHOD) property to `"html"`

---

For example:

```
private static final DocumentBuilderFactory sDocumentFactory;
private static DocumentBuilder sDocumentBuilder;
private static DOMImplementation sDomImplementation;

private static final TransformerFactory sTransformerFactory =
  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
private static Transformer sTransformer;

static {
  sDocumentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

  sDocumentFactory.setNamespaceAware( true );
  sDocumentFactory.setIgnoringComments( true );
  sDocumentFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace( true );

  try {
    sDocumentBuilder = sDocumentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    sDomImplementation = sDocumentBuilder.getDOMImplementation();
    sTransformer = sTransformerFactory.newTransformer();

    sTransformer.setOutputProperty( OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes" );
    sTransformer.setOutputProperty( INDENT, "no" );
    sTransformer.setOutputProperty( METHOD, "html" );
  } catch( final Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already setting that, both in the xsl and in the Java code, but it seems to be ignored. :-(

Answer (score 0):

**The way to output valid HTML with XSLT is to use the `<xsl:output>` instruction with its `method` attribute set to `html`.**

Here is a small example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <div>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="x/y/z"/>
     </div>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t/>
```

**the wanted result is produced** (the same result is produced by 8 different XSLT processors I am working with):

```
<div></div>
```

In case the unwanted output happens only with a specific XSLT processor, then this is an implementation issue with this particular processor and more an "xsltprocessors" than "xslt" question.

Comment: Thanks for the tag adjustment (again). I'm sure I'll learn eventually. :-)

Comment: As stated above, it seems to produce identical output whether I specify "html output" in the code, in the template, or not at all. :-(
What can I do if this really is a bug in the `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` (although it seems unlikely)?

Comment: @KlaymenDK: Some XSLT processors require the user to implement a class generally called something like "XSLTWriter" that controls the exact serialization. Also, some processors require additional settings in order to honor the value of the `method` attribute of `<xsl:output>`. Read the documentation of your XSLT processor. Unfortunately, my answer cannot cover the specifics of every XSLT processor. It provides what is necessary "from the XSLT side".You have the documentation, this becomes a very specific question that is not about the XSLT language per se, but about a specific XSLT processor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. This is all very new to me, so I'm unsure of what component may correspond to a given bug in my coding. I shall dig deeper in the documentation. (BTW, I'm working in Eclipse with the built-in Java libraries.)