# how to include script tag in an xsl file?

Tags: xslt

I'm working on an old site that uses java and xsl. How can I inculde a script file in an xsl file? Top of the file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:include href="shipmentPackageInfo.xsl"/>

<script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"></script>
```

breaks the app

-- UPDATE --

There is another file called pageHeader.xsl which has all the script tags inside of

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="PageHeaderData">
```

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at my answer to [XSLT wont allow me to use self-closing img and br tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560762/xslt-wont-allow-me-to-use-self-closing-img-and-br-tags/1560909#1560909)

Self closing script tags (`<script src="code.js"/`>) can cause the JavaScript files not to load, so inside of your XSLT, you may need to have some text inside the script tag to keep it from self closing and get it to work.

```
<script src="code.js>//</script>
```

Comment: For me, the javascript tag wouldn't even self-close itself, it would just completely strip the closing tag, causing some really bizarre behaviour. Putting the text between the tags fixes this luckily.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a solution here:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-20815.html

Put javascript code between `<xsl:text>` tag something like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<xsl:text>

javascript here

</xsl:text>

</script>
```

Comment: @contam Maybe you should suggest that to the forum member who posted this, since this is a direct quote from them ;)

Comment: you are right... I need to investigate if the forum source code is pasted from another forum :-)

Answer (score 8):

Oh, I do like this:

```
... ...
        </body>
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
var a_patch = function(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        var link = links[i];
        var text = link.innerHTML;
        ... ...
    }
};
a_patch();
]]></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must insert the script tag within a template block or it will break...

ie

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"></script>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Treemonkey. I tried your solution but it still breaks. Do I need to have the script inside <xsl:output method="html"/> ? However you can only have one output method per page?

Comment: So I guess I could add the script to the main pageHeader file and wrap it in a match so that the script only loads when that match is satisfied?

Answer (score 2):

The solution that works for:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding='utf-8' />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no" indent="yes" media-type="text/xhtml" />
```

is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">

         <![CDATA[

               /* Your Javascript code comes here  */

         ]]>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:comment>_</xsl:comment>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Here is a solution that works

Assuming this is your xsl and you are including xsl as you mentioned. In this case I called it `include.xsl`. I just call a template called headers that pipes out the javascript reference.

Main XSLT File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">
    <xsl:include href="include.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="headers"/>
        <bar>
           <xsl:value-of select="root"/>
        </bar>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

include.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
   <xsl:template name="headers">
        <script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"></script>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"/>
<bar>foo</bar>
```

Comment: Thanks. That just printed out <script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"></script> as a string onto the screen

Comment: Edited and a different code, I have tested this and it works. Essentially you can just call a template that has this or a set of javascripts

Comment: Using CDATA, I have tested this, you can also do `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ <script src="/fs/scripts/shipment/shipment.js"></script> ]]></xsl:text>` this will output it to the file

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/script.js">
     <xsl:comment>script</xsl:comment>
 </script>
```