# backbone app not calling in xsl but works fine in my local

Tags: xslt, backbone.js, requirejs, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to call the backbone app through xsl...
its working fine...but the problem is when i put inside a function its not working...
i tested with console.log inside that function..i am able to see console log...but its not calling backbone app,,
providing my code below...
the same function working fine when i dont put in xsl thats is when i test it in my local...
do i need to include anything in my xslor upgrade xsl...i dont see my app rendering in browser through xsl...but it works fine in my local without xsl...

http://xsltransform.net/bFukv8i/29

```
$(function() {    
                require(['common/quick-catalog/apps/quick-catalog']);
        });
```

Comment: Please see this link (http://forums.devshed.com/xml-programming-19/run-javascript-func-after-xslt-transformation-175584.html) particularly on the last part. I do not know if this will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to include script tag in an xsl file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611101/how-to-include-script-tag-in-an-xsl-file)